# where find clientid from console

Tags: email, google-analytics, measurement-protocol, clientid

I need to send some mails my users.
I will send it from console, so I have not any user's cookies.
And to track opening mails I insert img in letter body like this:

```
<img src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid={{UA}}&cid={{CID}}&uid={{UID}}..." alt="" />
```

How can I replace {{CID}} ?
Where should I find it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this hit to be connected to an existing user from your website you would need to record the client id when a user signs up for your emails, maintain a database that maps the recorded id to the e-mail address and the actual substitution would depend on your mail script. Since in this case the clientid is created in your users browser the only possible source would be the cookie.

If you just want to record a hit (without connecting it to existing users) then, as DalmTo pointed out, just use a random unique id.

If you do not have a client id, but have a way to identify the user on your website then you could also try the [UserId](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en) feature and session unification. In this case you would use a random client id and append your known user id as parameter.

Comment: Way to record clientid while user hits at signup page is good indeed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to the [measurement protocol documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference)

> - Protocol Version v v=1 The protocol version. The value should be 1.
> - Tracking ID tid tid=UA-123456-1 The ID that distinguishes to which Google Analytics property to send data.
> - Client ID cid cid=xxxxx An ID unique to a particular user.
> - Hit Type t t=pageview The type of interaction collected for a particular user.

this may also help [Email Tracking - Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/email)

> How can I replace {{CID}} ? Where should I find it?

It should be a unique number identifying this user, its basically used for session control.  Random Guid works.